# Filtering linked but empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Filter_empty_Rows()

Dim Row_nr As Integer

With Worksheets("Boutenlijst Kist B")

For Row_nr = 3 To 1009
    If Cells(Row_nr, 4).Value = "" Then
        Cells(Row_nr, 4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next Row_nr

End With

End Sub
```

This should hide all rows containing empty cells in column D. But it doesn´t. Because the empty cells still link to an other sheet. So there's is no real value but it is not empty as well.

Anyone got a workaround?

Comment: What appears in the cell where the link is where there is no data in the dependent cell?

Comment: In sheet both are empty. Source cell is blank in formula/value plane. Dependent cell has the reference mentioned in the formula/value plane.

Comment: Right. So when I type `=Sheet2!A1` into Sheet1 cell A1 and sheet2 Al is blank, it returns a `0` into Sheet1 cell A1. So your saying the way that you cell containing literally returns a blank?

Comment: It is blank but I guess Excel counts it as a zero. Like you and Rabbitman both confirm. Ill work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cell holds a reference to another cell and that cell has no value then the value of that cell's value is set to 0 by excel. So if you want one way to do it would be to do

```
If Cells(Row_nr, 4).Value = ""  Or Cells(Row_nr, 4).Value = 0 Then
```

If some of your data is going to be genuinely zero then it might be a little trickier. You can use `.Range.HasFormula` to see if it contains a formula or not and use that to decide if it is a bad piece of data or not.

If that isn't good enough then you can use `.Range.Formula` to get the actual formula in a cell and then use that to perform the analysis that you need.